# Async Callback Execution After setTimeout Problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise

In my react app, I have a function that somewhat simulates a call to an API. Is there a way I can synchronously run a callback function after this API request so that my data comes back in the order I sent it?

```
// the order in the array here matters
  const wordTypeArr = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3']

// loop sequentially through array
  wordTypeArr.forEach((v,i) => {
        getRandomWordFromAPI(v, addWord)
    })

//simulated "API" - can't modify this function
  const getRandomWordFromAPI = (type, callback) => {
    return setTimeout(function() {
      callback(
        type in dictionary ?
        sample(dictionary[type]) :
        null
      );
    }, (Math.random() * 750 + 250));
  }


//callback runs after response - update the state
  const addWord = (val) =>  {
    const newState = wordList
    newState.push(val)
    setWordList(newState);
}
```

As you can see, the `getRandomWordFromAPI` function returns a timeout function then executes the callback after the timeout asynchronously (out of order). This is undesirable, as my results must be in order.

Maybe I need to wrap `addWord` in a promise? or something similar?

Comment: "*simulates a call to an API*" - what kind of API is this? Notice that if it's a network call, in the real world results may come out of order as well.

Comment: You can pass the "i" parameter to your function call `getRandomWordFromAPI(v, addWord, i)`, and add it back to the result of yourAPI in your callback. When all requests are over, you have the data from the API maybe in a different order, but with a "number tag" that allows you to keep track of the correct original order.

Comment: @Bergi It is a network call. I'm trying to figure out how to write a program that will either keep the network requests in sync, or somehow track the data so that when all the responses return, I re-order it some how.

Comment: I would prefer Promise.all() and have the timeout trigger the resolve of those promises. The array returned after Promise.all() finishes, will be in the same order as the calls.

Comment: @Shilly Wow, I forgot that. Much simpler.

Comment: @Shilly I thought about that, but don't think I can do that without modifying the `getRandomWordFromAPI` function, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing that function would indeed be preferred as it'll make the code simpler to read. But since you can send `getRandomWordFromAPI` a callback, you can send the resolve function as the callback instead of addWord() and then chain the  addWord to the resolution.

I've put some parts of your code in comments, since we don't have the dictionary object and such, but the structure stays the same.

```js
// the order in the array here matters
const wordTypeArr = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3'];

//simulated "API" - can't modify this function
const getRandomWordFromAPI = (type, callback) => {
  return setTimeout(function() {
    callback( type );
    /*
    callback(
      type in dictionary ?
      sample(dictionary[type]) :
      null
    );*/
  }, (Math.random() * 750 + 250));
}

//callback runs after response - update the state
const addWord = (val) =>  {
  console.log( val );
/*
  const newState = wordList
  newState.push(val)
  setWordList(newState);
*/
  
}

const randomWords = wordTypeArr.map( word => {
  return new Promise(( resolve, reject ) => {
    getRandomWordFromAPI( word, resolve );
  });
});

Promise.all( randomWords ).then( words => words.forEach( addWord ));
```

Comment: Nice! I like this solution. I didnt think to add the resolve as the callback instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's 2019, promises are in, callbacks are out. On a more serious note, here's how you can refactor your code to make it work the way you want to:

```js
// mock the API
const getRandomWordFromAPI = (type, callback) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let word = `some-word-of-type-${type}`;
    callback(word);
  }, 1000)
}

// promisify the mocked API
const getRandomWordFromAPIPromise = (type) => new Promise(resolve => {
  getRandomWordFromAPI(type, resolve);
});

// fetch all data asynchronously, in order
const wordTypeArr = ['type1', 'type2', 'type3'];
const promises = wordTypeArr.map(getRandomWordFromAPIPromise);
Promise.all(promises).then(words => {
  // do whatever you want with the words
  console.log(words)
});
```